# I want two plugins TagbarToggle & WMToggle don't occur at the same time

Tags: vim

while,the next is my vimrc config

```
map <silent> <F12> :TagbarToggle<cr> :WMToggle<cr> :wincmd h<CR>
```

when TagbarToggle is visible,  will hidden TagbarToggle and WMToggle becomes visible.
Vice versa.

when all invisible,  will make all visible.
I want only one of then applears when i clicked

How could i do?

The follow is my train of thought, but i dont't know how to accomplish it

```
map <F12> :call ShowSlidebar()<cr>
func! ShowSlidebar()
        if TagbarToggle is visible
                exec "TagbarToggle"
                exec "WMToggle"
                return
        else
                exec "TlistToggle"
                return
                endif
endfunc
```

Comment: thank you Ingo for editing my unformatted content before I redit it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

it's ok now ,as follows:

```
470 function !IsBufEnabled()            
471     return (bufwinnr('[Buf List]') != -1)    
472 endfunction
473 
474 map <F12> :call ShowSlidebar()<cr>                                                                                                                                   
475 function! ShowSlidebar()            
476     if IsTagBarEnabled()            
477         exec "TagbarToggle"         
478         exec "WMToggle"             
479     elseif IsBufEnabled()           
480         exec "WMToggle"
481         exec "TagbarToggle"
482     else
483         exec "TagbarToggle"
484     endif
485 endfunction
```

Comment: Great that you've figured it out, and thanks for posting your complete solution; this will help others with the same problem.

Comment: well,some flaws  '[Buf List]' should be '\[Buf\ List]\'

Answer (score 0):

Some plugins provide a function to query whether it is currently active, some have a global variable. You need to delve into the plugin's code to find out.

If the plugin window has a fixed name, you can also check for visibility with this:

```
function! IsTagBarEnabled()
    return (bufwinnr('__Tagbar__') != -1)
endfunction
```